# How to unblock requests on my Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

If the saved state of the extension is true (on) requests from the website are blocked, if not, then nothing happens.

But I can't seem to remove the listener.
Here's my code:

```
chrome.storage.local.get(["button"], function(result) {
  console.log(result.button);
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabid, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status == "complete") {
    chrome.storage.local.get(["button"], function(result) {
      let savedStateOnOrOff = result.button;

      function onOroff() {
        if (savedStateOnOrOff === "on") {
          console.log(savedStateOnOrOff);
          chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
            function blocksRequests (details) {
              console.log("blocking:", details.url);
              return { cancel: true };
            },
            { urls: ["*://*.adjaranet.com/"] },
            ["blocking"]
          );
        } else if (savedStateOnOrOff === "off") {
          console.log(savedStateOnOrOff);
        }
      }

      onOroff();
    });
  }
});
```

Should be easy to remove it. Just chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(blocksRequests);
But that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Move `blockRequests` to global scope so the function reference stays the same. Use just its name both in addListener and removeListener.

Comment: How do I  move it to a global scope though?

Comment: By copypasting it after the last `});` in your pasted fragment;

Comment: I don't think its a global scope issue, but yes too much nesting going on here, yes take out the blocksRequests as is, put it anywhere, on the top of the file as is, from { to }

Comment: But the issue isn't that, it may work for a min or two, it will still misbehave. From my experience... they seem to work in dev until you produce the crx... long story short, I would enable persistence (although it's too expensive). I personally have a crazy amount of rules... so I use an extension manager to enable/disable the ext when needed.